# Connecting Remote mysql2 from rails app on ubuntu platform

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, remote-access, mysql2

i am using two ubuntu machines, one for `mysql2 server` and another one is for rails with `mysql2 client`, i am in need of connecting `mysql2 server` from rails app which is in another machine.  i used the configuration in `database.yml` :

```
default: &default

  adapter: mysql2

  encoding: utf8

  pool: 5

  username: root

  password: dani123*

  host: 192.168.1.185

  port: 3306

  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

but while i run `rake db:create` system throws the following `error`. kindly help me

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"dani123*", "host"=>"192.168.1.185", "port"=>3306, "socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", "database"=>"remotedb_development"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"dani123*", "host"=>"192.168.1.185", "port"=>3306, "socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", "database"=>"remotedb_test"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

Comment: post your `database yml`

Answer (score 1):

Your database.yml seem to be missing the `database` attribute. When you specify the database there, try with `hostname:port/db`